# Why is the electric field of Gauss law applicable for charges both in and around?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

We know that the L.H.S of Gauss law $E.dS$ is applicable for all charges in and around but R.H.S $Q$ is only for charges enclosed.

Now my question:

Lets say you have two gaussian surfaces of same size, one with charges around and the other with no charge around but enclosed with same charge as that of the first one.
*The value of $E$ in the first case is different from the second one, but still the R.H.S is the same.* Doesn't this contradict ? Please answer and correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a bit of clarity in the question here.But from the part I get:
Gauss' law states the flux through any surface is 1/Eo times the charge ENCLOSED by the surface.
So if the charge is outside, it doesnt count.Because an equak and opposite Electric field will be set up inside the body, resulting in a net 0(zero) Flux through the surface.
Hope this helps.